# Rewrite mobile url in address bar

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to use the RewriteRule to display thedomain.com rather than thedomain.com/mobile-main in a WordPress site. Tried the code variations below. I would like it to display the mobile-main page content and thedomain.com in the address bar.

```
RewriteRule ^mobile-main/$ %{HTTP_HOST} [L] #redirects
RewriteRule ^mobile-main/$ thedomain.com [L] #mobile-main url & page
RewriteRule ^mobile-main/$ index.php [L] #mobile-main url & page
```